# Ожидания одной хранимкой процедуры

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно собрать все ожидания, которые происходят при работе одной хранимой процедуры, например, за 1 час? Есть процедура, вызывается раза 2 в секунду, почти всегда работает ровно, довольно быстро. Но иногда резко замедляется, пока непонятно почему. Хочу посмотреть все ожидания, может сеть тупит, или блокировки возникают, или еще что-нибудь. SQL2016, план выполнения этой ХП не меняется.

Comment: [sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-procedure-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - не?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не, не оно. Мы бы получить ожидания всех типов со временем и количеством при работе процедуры. Сейчас прочитал, что есть Extended Events про ожидания. Буду в их сторону изучать